# 3 elements in a div element can't display in one line Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

```
<div class="count">
        <a class="aa">-</a>
        <input readonly="readonly" name="text1" value="10" type="text" id="relu1">      </input>
        <a class="aa">+</a> 
 </div>
```

I put three elements in the div and I want to three element appear on one line.

my css is like below:

```
.aa {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 22px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #99CC00;
        padding: 4px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

        .aa:active {
            opacity: 0.7;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

    .count {
        float: right;
    }

    div.ui-input-text {
        width: 30px !important;
    }
```

so strange in Jquery Mobile.

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it jQuery Mobile way by using [*controlgroup*](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/controlgroup/) and a bit of CSS.

```html
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
   <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-notext">-</a>
   <input type="text" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn" />
   <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext">+</a>
</div>
```

```css
.controlgroup-textinput{
   padding-top:.22em;
   padding-bottom:.22em;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/28voq4af/)**

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lawasn6e/)

```
<div class="count"> 
    <a href="#" class="aa">-</a>
    <input class="aa" name="text1" value="10" type="text" id="relu1" /> 
    <a href="#" class="aa">+</a> 
</div>


.aa {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: it's good.though @Omar have a better one.btw. thanks for your attension.